Influence function of expectation of conditional quantile
I am trying to derive the influence function of the estimand.
$$Pr(Y<m) = E(I(Y<m)) = E(E(I(Y<m)|X))$$
where the distribution of Y is depend on the X P(Y) = P(Y|X)P(X)
I appreciate your help!

What is your estimator?
